# Huge mail.que file on Exchange Server 2013

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2013

I'm facing an issue with an huge `mail.que` file on the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\TransportRoles\data\Queue`.

One of our users created an redirect loop and the mailbox blow with more than 100k bounce messages, and this file ended up filling the whole `C:` drive.

I was reading on the web what this file do, and it appears to keep some old queued messages, but I'm not sure if the information is correct.

As stated [here](http://msexchangeguru.com/2011/06/02/mail-que) it's safe to delete the file, with the following algorithm:

```
1. Run “Get-Queue” and take a look at the count of messages in HUB01
2. Goto services.msc and Pause the Microsoft Exchange Transport service
3. Again, run “Get-Queue” and ensure all pending messages are “zeroed” out
4. Once messages pending becomes zero, stop the Transport service
5. Move the mail.que file and all others to a new folder in the same location
6. Start the Transport service
```

I would like to know if this is really the right procedure, since the information on the link appears to apply for Exchange 2010.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

The procedure also applies to Exchange 2013. just in case here is also the link for Exchange 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125177%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx In this article it is also explained on how to move the mail.que fail to an alternate location.